# How can I install tensorflow_data_validation in python 3.7?

Tags: python, anaconda, python-3.7, tensorflow-data-validation

I use anaconda and I have python 3.7, I tried to install tensorflow_data_validation from anaconda's prompt but it gives me the following error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow_data_validation (from versions:)
No matching distribution found for tensorflow_data_validation
How can I solve that?